# Do you have an example code for pinescript str.split() function?

Tags: pine-script

Does anybody have an example code for pine script `str.split()` function?
The function does not work like java script. It returns a "series of string" type and it seems there is no way to define series of strings in pine script. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[str.split()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str%7Bdot%7Dsplit) does not return a "series of string".
It returns the id of an [array](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html) of strings.

This example will make it clear.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var string      myString        = 'my example text'
var string      separator_none  = ''
var string      separator_space = ' '


if barstate.islast
    array1 = str.split(myString, separator_none)    // no split character, so each letter in the string will be an element in the array
    array2 = str.split(myString, separator_space)   // split by space character so there will be 3 elements in the array
    
    var string labelText = na
    labelText := 'str.length(myString) = ' + str.tostring(str.length(myString))
    labelText += '\narray.size(array1) = ' + str.tostring(array.size(array1))
    labelText += '\nContent of array1 = '  + str.tostring(array1)
    labelText += '\narray.size(array2) = ' + str.tostring(array.size(array2))
    labelText += '\nContent of array2 = '  + str.tostring(array2)
    
    label.new(bar_index, close, labelText, style=label.style_label_left, textalign=text.align_left)
```

Which yields

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks,Actually when I want to plot that string array, the error messages rises and says it is 'series of string".for example:

c=str.tostring(close)
plotchar(ta.ema(close,200),title="close",char= c)

Comment: Yes, because `c` changes on every bar, it's a 'series of string', but `plotchar()` requires a constant for the `char` parameter. If you need to put changing text on a chart, it should be done with labels. See [Labels](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html#labels) in the reference manual.

Answer (score 3):

This will return "hello" on a label of the last bar

```
if barstate.islast
    txt = "hello,there"
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=low, text=array.get(str.split(txt, ","),0))
```

Comment: thank you, bjon already answered.